# Creating methods with partial

Tags: python-2.7

```
class MyClass(FinderClass):
    def _find(self, search, attribute):
        if attribute == 'ip':
            locator = "some_locator"
        if attribute == 'name':
            locator = "other_locator"
        return self.finder.find(search, locator)

    def find_by_ip(self, ip):
        return self._find(ip, 'ip')
```

Can I rewrite the above example using functools' partial? What I would like to have if it's possible: argument ip should be named ip and not search, function should be created inside of the class.

What I would like to get is something simmilar to this:

```
class MyClass(FinderClass):
    def _find(self, search, attribute):
        if attribute == 'ip':
            locator = "some_locator"
        if attribute == 'name':
            locator = "other_locator"
        return self.finder.find(search, locator)

    find_by_ip = functools.partial(_find, attribute='ip')
```

This works but you have to call it like this which is not cool:

```
mc = MyClass()
mc.find_by_ip(mc, '127.0.0.1')
```

Also argument to the function is called `search` and not `ip`, but this is kinda OK.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `functools.partial(self._find, attribute="ip")`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't use `self._find` as you do not have reference to `self` when defining a method inside of a class. And yes I would like to use partial but it gets complicated with passing self and binding function to class.

Comment: Whether you can use `self` depends on what you want to do, and where, and that's not at all clear from your question.